# UIScrollView UITableView ScrollViewDelegateの判定について

Tags: ios, tableview, iphone, scrollview, delegate

やりたいことは、ScrollViewとTableViewの判断です。
二つともデリゲートでつなげているのですが、TableviewはScrollのデリゲートがつながってしまいます・・・
なので、どちらのViewでスクロールされているのかが判断できない状態です。

現在

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
```

こちらで、スクロールが縦にされた場合TableView横でされた場合ScrollViewと判断させているのですが、もっとよいやり方があるのではないかと考えています。
どなたかご存知の方がいらっしゃればぜひご教授ください。
現在はこちらで判断しております。

```
CGPoint currentPoint = [scrollView contentOffset];
if(self.scrollBeginingPoint.y > currentPoint.y){
        //上方向スクロール検知        
    }else if(self.scrollBeginingPoint.y < currentPoint.y){
        //下方向スクロール検知      
    }
```

Comment: 行の最初に半角スペース4つをつけるとコードが綺麗になります。書式に関しては[ヘルプに書いています](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)。とりあえず読めるように編集させました。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。　
助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tag`でできると思います。

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag

tagに適当な値をセット(ここではtableViewに2、scrollViewに1）して、

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(scrollView.tag == 1){
        //scrollView
    }else if(scrollView.tag == 2){
        //tableView
    }
}
```

とすれば振り分けられます。

タグはstoryboardからも設定できます。

[image: タグ]

Comment: こちら、一番簡単に実装できました。
どうもありがとうございます。
助かりました。

Answer (score 2):

引数で渡ってきた`scrollView`を、プロパティなどで保持している`scrollView`や`tableView`と比較して処理を分けると良いと思います。

Answer (score 2):

既に回答にでているように、基本的にはインスタンスの`property`や`tag`などに情報を保持しておいて一意な情報を元に比較するのが良いと思います。

ただ、もしTableViewやScrollViewが動的に生成され、１つのController内にscrollViewDidScrollのscrollView候補がたくさんあるような場合であれば`isKindOfClass`を使って、クラスの種類によって分岐させるという方法もあります。

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if([scrollView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]] ){
        //scrollViewがUITableViewの場合
    }else{
       //scrollViewがUITableView以外のScrollViewの場合
    }
}
```

「一意なインスタンス」として分岐させたい（`property`や`tag`で識別)のか、「クラスの種類」で分岐(`isKindOfClass`で識別)させたいのかで要件によって使い分けるのが良いと思います。(後者は少し特殊なケースかもしれませんが。。)

Comment: 動的に生成したときに是機使わせていただきます。
ありがとうございます。